# the for loop check the user and every time the both if statement is checked i want only one statement should be checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim LoginUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)

    Dim sFormat As String = "00.00"
    'Dim LoginUser = "P002"
    Dim sqlapt As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from wpchannel", connection)
    Dim sqlds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim sqldt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    sqlapt.Fill(sqlds, "wpaccess")
    sqldt = sqlds.Tables(0)
    'Dim sum As Double
    Dim row As DataRow
    For Each row In sqldt.Rows
        Dim strDetail As String
        strDetail = row("username")
        lbluserchk.Text = strDetail
        If lbluserchk.Text = LoginUser.ToString Then

            Dim sqlapt1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from wpchannel where username='" + LoginUser.ToString + "'", connection)
            Dim sqlds1 As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim sqldt1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
            sqlapt1.Fill(sqlds1, "wpchannel")
            sqldt1 = sqlds1.Tables(0)
            Dim username As String = sqldt1.Rows(0).Item(1).ToString
            Dim productid As String = sqldt1.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString
            lblcheck1.Text = username.ToString
            lblcheck2.Text = productid
            'New check
            Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim sqlquery2 = "select convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, dn.curdatetime),20) as DnDate ,DN.telcoid As TelecoId,round(convert(decimal(18,2),DN.USD),2) as USD,DN.DNStatus As DnStatus,count(*) as Total,sum(round(convert(decimal(18,2),DN.USD),2)) as subtotal from DN left join MO on DN.moid = mo.linkid where mo.channeltype in (select channelid from wpchannel where username='" + LoginUser.ToString + "') Group by  convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, dn.curdatetime),20),DN.telcoid,DN.USD,DN.DNStatus order by DnDate,dn.telcoid,dnstatus,USD"
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery2, connection)
            da.Fill(ds, "MO")
            dt = ds.Tables(0)
            ViewState("dtpayment") = dt
            Session("dtpayment") = dt
            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).Font.Bold = True
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).ForeColor = Color.Black
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).Text = " Grand Total:"
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right


            Dim sum As Double = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute("SUM(" + (dt.Columns(5).ColumnName) + ")", String.Empty))
            Dim footernum As Double = sum.ToString
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(3).Text = footernum.ToString()
            Dim sumnum As Double = sum.ToString

            lblsum.Text = sumnum.ToString()
            ViewState("dt") = dt
            ViewState("sort") = "Asc"
            VerifyRenderingInServerForm(GridView1)
            Exit For
        Else
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter
            Dim ds1 As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim dt1 As DataTable = New DataTable()
            'Dim sqlquery1 = "select convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, dn.curdatetime),20) as DnDate ,DN.telcoid As TelecoId,round(convert(decimal(18,2),DN.USD),2) as USD,DN.DNStatus As DnStatus,count(*) as Total from DN left join MO on DN.moid = mo.linkid Group by  convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, dn.curdatetime),20),DN.telcoid,DN.USD,DN.DNStatus order by DnDate DESC,dn.telcoid,dnstatus,USD"
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            cmd.Connection = connection
            cmd.CommandText = "logReport"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da1.Fill(ds1, "MO")
            dt1 = ds1.Tables(0)
            ViewState("dtpayment") = dt1
            Session("dtpayment") = dt1
            GridView1.DataSource = dt1
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).Font.Bold = True
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).ForeColor = Color.Black
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).Text = " Grand Total:"
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(2).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right

            Dim sum As Double = Convert.ToDouble(dt1.Compute("SUM(" + dt1.Columns(2).ColumnName + ")", String.Empty)) * Convert.ToDouble(dt1.Compute("SUM(" + dt1.Columns(4).ColumnName + ")", String.Empty))
            Dim footernum As Double = sum
            GridView1.FooterRow.Cells(3).Text = footernum.ToString()
            Dim sumnum As Double = sum.ToString
            lblsum.Text = sumnum.ToString()

            ViewState("dt") = dt1
            ViewState("sort") = "Asc"
            VerifyRenderingInServerForm(GridView1)
            Continue For
        End If
        'Exit Sub
    Next row
Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.Text = ex.ToString
    'jscript = ("<script language=""JavaScript"">alert(""Error! Cannot conect to the database."");</script>")
    'RegisterClientScriptBlock(x, jscript)
End Try
```

Comment: I only see one IF statement there

Comment: yes but the else is excuted on every user check in table by for loop

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the  line with the `If` statement and then inspect the values of `lbluserchk.Text` and `LoginUser`.  I suspect that their values are not what you expect them to be.